# How do I show only the graph of a chart (No Legend, No Title, Minimum Space Used) in Silverlight 3.0?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I'm writing a Silverlight application that is showing a pie chart of completed items as an item in a DataGrid.  I currently can get the graph to show as an item in the DataGrid using a DataGridTemplateColumn.

My problem is the grid blows out the height of the data row because it has a title and a legend and a lot of allocated whitespace around it.  I JUST want to show the pie chart only, with no extra padding or information.

I have found a few convoluted styling ways to do this but they seem to throw syntax errors (perhaps they are Silverlight 2.0 solutions?)

Does anyone have a working way of doing this in Silverlight 3.0?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly does "blows out the height of the data row" mean?

Comment: Sorry, I'm Australian.. it meant.. "makes the height of each row very big to accommodate the whole size of the graph"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chart can be styled extensively, if you want to have a super-frugal chart which basically only has a ChartArea and thats all then you can supply a minimal template for it:-

```
<charting:Chart>
    <charting:Chart.Style>
        <Style TargetType="charting:Chart">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:Chart">
                        <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </charting:Chart.Style>
    <charting:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" IndependentValuePath="Value" DependentValuePath="ID" />
</charting:Chart>
```

Note I'm using the Nov09 Silverlight 3 tool kit.  The above contains just the PieChart no borders, padding, title, legend, gradient background or anything but the raw chart itself.

Comment: Thanks Anthony!  I also found you can auto-generate these styles by (in Blend) right-clicking on the graph -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy...

This will generate the full layout and then you can trim away what you don't need!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a negative margin to the Pie chart.  This will cause the chart to be placed lower in the grid and crop the (invisible) title.

```
Margin = "-10,-10,-10,-10"
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to work.  It appears to just move the border, with the graph staying there.. and this doesn't solve my legend issue either.  Thanks for the suggestion.

This is what I tried:
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="CompleteGraph" Margin="-10,-10,-10,-10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="Width">